# Enabling optimistic locking - DynamoDBVersionAttribute on an existing table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an existing table in production on which I would like to enable optimistic locking. The documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBVersionAttribute.html) says that the "new" objects will be assigned version number 1.

Now if I add the following attribute to the table, how will this will value be set for an existing item? since my table already contains production data how will the `updateItem()` operation work?

```
@DynamoDBVersionAttribute
public Long getVersion() { return version; }
public void setVersion(Long version) { this.version = version;}
```

Will the first `UpdateItem` operation assign version = 1 if the existing version value is `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's correct, the first update from Null will set the value to 1.

As always, do a test in a development environment before making any changes to production.